# Processing Android Image returns NullPointerException when selecting image

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I have this android app with a button where you can choose image. once you click the image it will get the value and pass it on `onActivityResult()`

is this line of code I always get an error `NullPointerException`

```
 Uri uri = data.getData();
 String path = FileUtil.getRealPath(this, uri);
 mPhotoUri = Uri.parse(path);
```

the value of `uri` is `content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A319` why would I get this error?

Log

```
05-19 16:20:18.679: E/galleryselector(13660): java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString
05-19 16:20:18.679: E/galleryselector(13660):   at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java:467)
05-19 16:20:18.679: E/galleryselector(13660):   at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java:457)
05-19 16:20:18.679: E/galleryselector(13660):   at android.net.Uri.parse(Uri.java:429)
05-19 16:20:18.679: E/galleryselector(13660):   at com.galleryselector.PostActivity.onActivityResult(PostActivity.java:253)
05-19 16:20:18.679: E/galleryselector(13660):   at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5423)
05-19 16:20:18.679: E/galleryselector(13660):   at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3361)
05-19 16:20:18.679: E/galleryselector(13660):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3408)
05-19 16:20:18.679: E/galleryselector(13660):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:135)
05-19 16:20:18.679: E/galleryselector(13660):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244)
05-19 16:20:18.679: E/galleryselector(13660):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-19 16:20:18.679: E/galleryselector(13660):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-19 16:20:18.679: E/galleryselector(13660):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-19 16:20:18.679: E/galleryselector(13660):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-19 16:20:18.679: E/galleryselector(13660):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-19 16:20:18.679: E/galleryselector(13660):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-19 16:20:18.679: E/galleryselector(13660):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-19 16:20:18.679: E/galleryselector(13660):   at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:126)
05-19 16:20:18.679: E/galleryselector(13660):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

the FileUtil Class

```
  public static String getRealPath(Context context, Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaColumns.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();

    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA);
    String path = cursor.getString(columnIndex);

    cursor.close();

    return path;
  }
```

this Appears when I debug using KITKAT

Comment: Could You please share the logcat with us?

Comment: `FileUtil.getRealPath(this, uri)` returns `null`. What is the `FileUtil` class? please, show import for that

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
getAbsolutePath(data.getData()) + "|").split("\\|")


public String getAbsolutePath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaColumns.DATA };
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } else
            return null;
    }
```

this may help you